# HTML Email : Table overflows on Mobile?

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, gmail

I have created an HTML email using `HandlebarsJS` for placeholders.

It renders fine on all `desktop` clients, however on `Mobile` the table spills out over onto the right hand side of page (see example below), note that inline CSS is necessary to render on Gmail.

[image]

How can I ensure the table is centered on Mobile as well as on desktop?

**Table code:**

```html
<div class="table" style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;">
  <table id="carTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="504" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: solid 1px #cccccc;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;">
        <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Car Number</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Group</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Risk</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Cost</th>
        <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Result</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- {{#each parts}} -->
      <tr style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;">
        <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{number}}</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{group}}</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{risk}}</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{cost}}</td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{result}}</td>
      </tr>
      <!--{{/each}} -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your table to a fixed width of "504" which translates to "504px". If you want it to be responsive on mobile, then try setting it to "100%" like this:

```html
<div class="table" style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;">
    <table id="carTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: solid 1px #cccccc;">
        <tbody>
        <tr style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;">
            <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Car Number</th>
            <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Group</th>
            <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Risk</th>
            <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Cost</th>
            <th style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #DFDFDF;text-align: left;">Result</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- {{#each parts}} -->
        <tr style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;">
            <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{number}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{group}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{risk}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{cost}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;font-stretch: normal;font-style: normal;line-height: 1.38;letter-spacing: normal;color: #333333;height: 30px;transition: all 0.3s;background: #FAFAFA;text-align: left;">{{result}}</td>
        </tr>
        <!--{{/each}} -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I would highly suggest you use a framework for building your email templates such as [MJML](https://mjml.io/) or [Foundation for Email](https://github.com/foundation/foundation-emails) as this will make your life a lot easier when targeting different email clients and making responsive emails.

Comment: This does not solve the problem and actually makes the table overflow on Desktop as well as mobile?